# Background thread Tomcat Struts2

Tags: tomcat, struts2, background-process

I have a web application using struts2 and tomcat 6 as a server. I have to do some logic that is in a jar file, but this take some time to finish. That's why I want to send the data from the execute method to that class in a separate thread, because if I use the class in the execute method I have to wait until all the logic is finished.

I've tried with execAndWait interceptor, the logic is in a separate thread, but I can't do anything in my application until that thread is finished (because of the per-session of execAndWait).

I want to know if there's another way to process the logic in another thread?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Executor Framework](http://pragmaticjava.blogspot.com/2008/12/java-5-concurrency-executor-framework.html) that was added in Java 5.

Comment: Thank you it works well, The only detail you have to check is how to implement the ExecutorService for a better performance.

Comment: I'm glad that helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Struts2 with Spring you could use the Spring TaskExecutor.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

Comment: I'll check this out Alex to compare performance between Spring and Executor. Thank you